# GetPost Information not inserting into table

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, xampp

I am currently using the CodeIgniter4 framework with PHP, this is supposed to get the name/id of each input form and the information inside, and then put that info into the their respective columns, I tried dd($data); to make sure it's receiving the information but when it actually does try to put in the info, it skips Street Number, City, State and Country, I have made sure that the model is getting the right columns in the table, and as far as I'm aware, there is no reason for this code to not work.

Function Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\Admin\Theme;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use App\Models\Admin\UserModel;
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class Auth extends BaseController
{
    use ResponseTrait;
    public function Register()
    {
        $model = new UserModel();
        
        $data = [
            "name"=>$this->request->getPost('name'),
            "email"=>$this->request->getPost('email'),
            "password"=>password_hash($this->request->getPost('password'),PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            "phone"=>$this->request->getPost('phone'),
            "street_number"=>$this->request->getPost('street_number'),
            "street"=>$this->request->getPost('route'),
            "apartment"=>$this->request->getPost('subpremise'),
            "city"=>$this->request->getPost('locality'),
            "postal_code"=>$this->request->getPost('postcode'),
            "state"=>$this->request->getPost('state'),
            "country"=>$this->request->getPost('country'),
            "latitude"=>$this->request->getPost('latitude'),
            "longitude"=>$this->request->getPost('longitude'),
            "place_id"=>$this->request->getPost('place_id'),
        ];
    
    
        $model->insert($data); 
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with("message","
        <div class='alert alert-success solid alert-dismissible fade show'>
            <svg viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' height='24' stroke='currentColor' stroke-width='2' fill='none' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' class='me-2'><polyline points='9 11 12 14 22 4'></polyline><path d='M21 12v7a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h11'></path></svg>  
            <strong>Success!</strong> Account successfully created.
            <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-label='btn-close'>
            </button>
        </div>
    ");
}
```

Model Code:

```
class UserModel extends Model
{

    // Product Table
    protected $table="users";
    protected  $primaryKey="id";

    protected $allowedFields=['name',
                             'email',
                             'password',
                             'role_id',
                             'activation_code',
                             'active',
                             'phone',
                             'street_number',
                             'street',
                             'apartment',
                             'city',
                             'postal_code',
                             'state',
                             'country',
                             'latitude',
                             'longitude',
                             'place_id',
                            ];
}
```

Image of Inserted Data Inside Table:

[image: Image of Inserted Data Inside Table]

Image of Data Received:

[image: Image of Data Received]

It's VERY strange because some info is inserted but some aren't.

Comment: can you use `$this->db->last_query();` to find the exact query that is executing?

Comment: I received this error: 
Undefined property: App\Controllers\Admin\Theme\Auth::$db

Comment: you can try this `$model->getLastQuery()->getQuery()` or this `$model->db->getLastQuery()->getQuery()`

Comment: Huh, it seems like it isn't inserting the address into the table, not sure why.

`INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `phone`) VALUES ('Test', 'test@testy.com', '$2y$10$IM7IaYcA7lPhG.uSwbnRm.pAEC3dqFQ4V5.VVRidthU6vmCzLIE0K', '0400000000')`